# Fatal errorLNK2019 and LNK1120 while use LZOpenFile?

Tags: file, fatal-error

I am Working on Windows Vista, and have the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

// ...

INT vint = NULL;

vint = LZOpenFile(lpFileName,lpReOpenBuf,wStyle);
```

When I build my program, it fails with linking errors:

> fatal error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _LZOpenFileW@12 referenced in function "int_stdcall LZOpenFile(wchar_t *,struct _OFSTRUCT *,unsigned short)" (?LZOpenFile@@YGHPA_WPAU_OFSTRUCT@@G@Z)
>
> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Help me to resolve this problem... Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against Lz32.lib. Make sure you have this lib listed in your linking options.

Answer (score 1):

thank you, Matthew Talbert 
first select properties from solution explorer (right click),select linker options and then select command line options ,insert Lz32.lib on that place ......now build succeed without any fatal error......

Answer (score 1):

To link against Lz32.lib in MS Visual 2008:

Project --> Properties

Then see in 
--> Linker
--> Input

And in Additional Dependencies simply add Lz32.lib